# how to used current lat long in leaflet.map("map").setView in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

```
this.map = leaflet.map("map").setView([this.latitude, this.longitude], 10);
```

also used this code for get current lat long

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then( pos =>{ 

this.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
this.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;

}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

but it not render 1st time in  real device.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling

```html
this.map = leaflet.map("map").setView([this.latitude, this.longitude], 10);
```

before geolocation resolves the device coords??

It can take some time for a device to resolve its position. If you are setting the view and rendering the map too soon then that might explain why you are having issues on the first load.

Setting the view of the leaflet map in the .then method could resolve your issue. However, you might want to deal with the long resolution time, particularly if the map is a key component of your app. IE, you dont want your users looking at a blank screen whilst your map loads.